# Не могу зайти на Stack Exchange и пользоваться чатами

Tags: поддержка, чат

Сегодня понял, что не могу пользоваться чатами, потому что не могу войти на Stack Exchange.

Когда я перехожу в чат (по [ссылке](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54360304#54360304), которая создается под постом при увеличении числа комментариев), не могу писать, и система не видит меня под логином.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На Stackoverflow я захожу через vk, а на Stack Exchange такого варианта нет.
При этом уведомления с чатов отлично приходят.

У меня один раз только получилось туда зайти, но почему-то только из режима "инкогнито".

Comment: Как переходите? Ссылки? Картинки? Нужно больше конкретики.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, когда разрастается обсуждение под постом можно создать чат, ссылка добавляется в комменты. Вот по ней и перехожу.

Comment: Внесите эту информацию в сообщение через кнопку [edit]. Добавьте ссылку на подходящий комментарий с ссылкой в чат. Приложите скриншот, где видно, что писать в чат нельзя и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала попробовал отключить все расширения, но это не помогло.
В итоге проблема решилась банальной чисткой кэша страницы, выходом и повторным входом на Stack Overflow.